# Perform basic calculation with a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm playing around with Firebase's cloud functions trying to get to grips with the basics. I've been watching Jen Parsons videos on YouTube and I understand how her example of sanitising posts works where the function replaces specific words.

I next want to take a look at performing calculations on data which is entered into the database but I have no idea how I would achieve this. The data would look something like this:

[image: Example data]

And when someone enters a value it is automatically doubled by the cloud function.

I know its basic but I don't know how I would do this. The code for the sanitising posts is here which may be something for me to work from and use I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.sanitizePost = functions.database.ref('/posts/{pushId}').onWrite(function (event) {
  var post = event.data.val();
  if (post.sanitized) {
    return;
  }
  post.sanitized = true;
  post.title = sanitize(post.title);
  post.body = sanitize(post.body);
  return event.data.ref.set(post);
});

function sanitize(s) {
  var sanitizedText = s;
  sanitizedText = sanitizedText.replace(/\bstupid\b/ig, "wonderful");
  return sanitizedText;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code that uses transaction to double the value.

```
exports.calculation = functions.database.ref('/Calculations/{idKey}')
.onCreate(event =>  {

    return event.data.ref.transaction(function (current_value) { return (current_value || 0) * 2; });

});
```

But take a look that I'm using the onCreate event. If would like to use onWrite or onUpdate this could lead to a infinite loop.

So if you need to use these events you may need to take care and check some other variable to calculate elapsed time and avoid the infinite loop like mentioned on this documentation https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/cloud-functions-realtime-database.html